# JpGraph on Windows via Composer - Class not found

Tags: windows, composer-php, phpspreadsheet, jpgraph

I've installed PHPSpreadsheet and JpGraph via composer on a Windows machine. I'm using the following code but am getting the error "Class 'Graph' not found". Is there another way I need to be including JpGraph?

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Renderer\JpGraph;

$graph = new Graph(400,300);
```

Comment: You should probably use `new JpGraph()` - right now you're using different class than in import.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Class 'PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Renderer\JpGraph' not found in S:\IIS\_scripts\test.php:5

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

jpgraph/jpgraph package is outdated and abandoned.

Since version 1.25 `PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet` supports `mitoteam/jpgraph` package which is actual and has php 8.2

After installing both packages by composer you need to setup PhpSpreadsheet to use `mitoteam/jpgraph` as renderer:

```
\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Settings::setChartRenderer(
  \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Renderer\MtJpGraphRenderer::class
);
```

Additional details:

- https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet#chart-export
- https://packagist.org/packages/mitoteam/jpgraph

Comment: MiSHuTka, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)